# data repository based on std::map and boost::any: conversion errors

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I am trying to implement a handy data repository or
knowledge base for a little program of mine.
I use a std::map of boost::any's to hold various pieces of
information. For debugging and safety purposes, I have
an extra safe accessor ''getVal()'' for the data.

A snippet says more than a thousand words:

**EDIT:  <<< Old snippet replaced by complete reproduction of error >>>**

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::map<int, boost::any> KnowledgeBase_base;
/**
 *  * KnowledgeBase is simply a storage for information,
 *   * accessible by key.
 *    */
class KnowledgeBase: public KnowledgeBase_base
{
    public:
        template<typename T>
            T getVal(const int idx)
            {
                KnowledgeBase_base::iterator iter = find(idx);
                if(end()==iter)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Knowledgebase: Key " << idx << " not found!";
                    return T();
                }
                return boost::any_cast<T>(*iter);
            }

        bool isAvailable(int idx)
        {
            return !(end()==find(idx));
        }

    private:
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    KnowledgeBase kb;
    int i = 100;
    kb[0] = i;
    kb[1] = &i;

    std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(kb[0]) << std::endl; // works
    std::cout << *boost::any_cast<int*>(kb[1]) << std::endl; // works
    std::cout << kb.getVal<int>(0) << std::endl; // error
    std::cout << kb.getVal<int*>(1) << std::endl; // error
    std::cout << "done!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

When I store a `Something*` in it, and try a
**EDIT: as visible in the updated example code above, it doesn't need to be a pointer!**
Something* = kb->getVal it complains with:
**boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
  what():  boost::bad_any_cast: failed conversion using boost::any_cast**

If I use KnowledgeBase::operator[] it works.
Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: You should add the code that is actually giving the error. Write a simple test that includes an element and tries to extract it with the `getVal` template and then post the code and error. Also note that it is not recommended to derive from STL (or any other class that was not meant to be extended). Also your `getVal` should probably be `const`.

Comment: Usual nitpick that standard library containers are not really intended to be derived from.

Comment: I changed the code to something you can copy&paste and run to try out.
The reason why the code is not working still eludes me. It would be of tremendous help to me if this would work. Thx to everyone investing brain cycles in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh short_n_crisp_exclamatory_word,{!}

I completely forgot that the iterator points to a `std::pair` !
Shame on me!

Sorry for bothering.

The correct last line of getVal is:

```
        return boost::any_cast<T>(iter->second);
    }
```

Thx, anyway.